# Состояние выбранных CheckBox при переходе на другой фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, expandablelistview

У меня есть `ExpandableListView`. И при клике по `groupItem` переходит на другую страницу то есть делаю replace `Fragment`. А у дочерних `Item`-ах `checkbox`ы. Перехожу и обратно когда нажимаю назад или вообще когда открываю эту страницу все отмеченные `CheckBox` стираются.

**Мой адаптер:**

```
public class RubExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<RubricsModel> rubrics;
private List<VacancyModel> listForRubricListView;
private List<VacancyModel> listForSubRubricListView;
private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;
public static int rubricPage = 1;
public static int rubricId;
public static int subRubricPage = 1;
public static int subRubricId;
FragmentManager fm;

public RubExpandAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RubricsModel> rubrics, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rubrics = rubrics;
    fm = fragmentManager;
    listForRubricListView = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<SubRubricsModel> chList = rubrics.get(groupPosition)
            .getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    final int mChildPosition = childPosition;
    SubRubricsModel subRubricsModel = (SubRubricsModel) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.rubrics_child_row_layout, null);
    }
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvsubrubricsfr);
    tv.setText(subRubricsModel.getSubRubricName());

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
        }
    });

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

            } else {

                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
            }
        }
    });

    if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {
        boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
        checkBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);

    } else {
        boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];

        mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<SubRubricsModel> chList = rubrics.get(groupPosition)
            .getItems();

    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return rubrics.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return rubrics.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final RubricsModel rubricsModel = (RubricsModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.rubrics_group_row_layout, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvrubricsfr);
    tv.setText(rubricsModel.getRubricName());
    ImageView indicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGroupIndicator);

    if (isExpanded) {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);

    } else {
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_right);
    }

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RubFragment.searchByRubrics = true;
            rubricId = rubricsModel.getRubricID();
            searchByRubric(String.valueOf(rubricId));

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как сохранить состояние `Checkbox`
 и еще как посчитать количество чекнутых `checkBox`?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сохранять фрагмент в памяти с помощью `setRetainInstance(true)`.
При сохранении фрагмента можно рассчитывать на то, что все его поля сохранят прежние значения.

**UPD**

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction(); RubricsResultFragment fragment = new RubricsResultFragment(); 
fragment.setRetainInstance(true); 
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, fragment, "RUBRICS_RESULT"); 
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("RUBRICS_RESULT"); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Не помогло((... Написал так: `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                                RubricsResultFragment fragment = new RubricsResultFragment();
                                fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: А почему у Вас `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` ?

Comment: Не помню если честно) Из за этого?

Comment: я обновила ответ - попробуйте так

Comment: Сработало, то есть с чеками. но теперь на экране предыдущий фрагмент а на нем фрагмент который открыл... а с replace не получится?

Comment: да нет, можно и с `replace`